# WSO2 ESB treat HTTP 404 as network error

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have two endpoints. I want them to load balance traffic, as well as act as a failover mechanism. Saying failover I mean, that when one endpoint is not responding (target service is down, for any reason), the second one takes all the traffic. I use the following configuration:

```
<send>
    <endpoint>
        <loadbalance algorithm="org.apache.synapse.endpoints.algorithms.RoundRobin">
            <endpoint name="bsz2_mock_ep1">
                <address uri="http://10.16.105.197:8080/bsz2_mock"/>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint name="bsz2_mock_ep2">
                <address uri="http://10.16.105.198:8080/bsz2_mock"/>
            </endpoint>
        </loadbalance>
    </endpoint>
</send>
```

In this scenario, when one of the target JBoss instance is down, all the requests are passed to the second one, which is ok.

The problem is, that when JBoss instance is booting, and before the application is up, it replies with HTTP 404. In this case, ESB generates fault message like `Unexpected response received. HTTP response code : 404 HTTP status : Not Found exception : First Element must contain the local name, Envelope , but found html`. I'd like loadbalance endpoint to advance and try the next endpoint, as it is done for connection failure errors.

I've tried to specify HTTP protocol violation (101506) and Response processing failure (101510) error codes to mark endpoint as suspended, as well as to mark it for suspension (see docs: http://wso2.com/library/articles/wso2-enterprise-service-bus-endpoint-error-handling/)

```
<endpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="bsz2_mock_ep2">
   <http uri-template="http://10.16.105.198:8080/bsz2_mock" method="post">
      <suspendOnFailure>
         <errorCodes>101506,101510,101503,101504</errorCodes>
         <initialDuration>1000</initialDuration>
         <progressionFactor>1.2</progressionFactor>
         <maximumDuration>5000</maximumDuration>
      </suspendOnFailure>
      <markForSuspension>
         <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
         <retryDelay>1000</retryDelay>
      </markForSuspension>
   </http>
</endpoint>

<endpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="bsz2_mock_ep2">
   <http uri-template="http://10.16.105.198:8080/bsz2_mock" method="post">
      <suspendOnFailure>
         <initialDuration>1000</initialDuration>
         <progressionFactor>1.2</progressionFactor>
         <maximumDuration>5000</maximumDuration>
      </suspendOnFailure>
      <markForSuspension>
         <errorCodes>101506,101510,101503,101504</errorCodes>
         <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
         <retryDelay>1000</retryDelay>
      </markForSuspension>
   </http>
</endpoint>
```

I'm using WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 with NHttp transport (not the default pass-through).

How can I configure ESB to fulfill my requirement?

Answer (score 0):

The requirement can be achieved using the configuration given in [1]

Find the ESB console for the given scenario in [2]

[1]

```
<definitions xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
   <proxy name="loadbalance"
          transports="https http"
          startOnLoad="true"
          trace="disable">
      <description/>
      <target>
         <inSequence onError="myfault">
            <send>
               <endpoint>
                  <loadbalance algorithm="org.apache.synapse.endpoints.algorithms.RoundRobin">
                     <endpoint name="e1">
                        <address uri="http://localhost:9001/services/SimpleStockQuoteService"/>
                     </endpoint>
                     <endpoint name="e2">
                        <address uri="http://localhost:9000/services/SimpleStockQuoteService"/>
                     </endpoint>
                     <endpoint name="e3">
                        <address uri="http://localhost:9003/services/SimpleStockQuoteService"/>
                     </endpoint>
                  </loadbalance>
               </endpoint>
            </send>
         </inSequence>
      </target>
   </proxy>
   <sequence name="myfault">
      <log level="custom">
         <property name="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"  value="Log sequence hit"/>
      </log>
      <drop/>
   </sequence>
</definitions>
```

[2]

```
[2015-02-01 14:36:20,988]  INFO - CarbonAuthenticationUtil 'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2015-02-01 14:36:20,987+0530]
[2015-02-01 14:37:23,553]  INFO - TimeoutHandler This engine will expire all callbacks after : 120 seconds, irrespective of the timeout action, after the specified or optional timeout
[2015-02-01 14:37:23,563]  WARN - ConnectCallback Connection refused or failed for : localhost/127.0.0.1:9001
[2015-02-01 14:37:23,567]  WARN - EndpointContext Endpoint : e1 will be marked SUSPENDED as it failed
[2015-02-01 14:37:23,568]  WARN - EndpointContext Suspending endpoint : e1 - current suspend duration is : 30000ms - Next retry after : Sun Feb 01 14:37:53 IST 2015
[2015-02-01 14:37:23,568]  WARN - LoadbalanceEndpoint AnonymousEndpoint Detect a Failure in a child endpoint : Endpoint [e1]
[2015-02-01 14:37:23,570]  WARN - ConnectCallback Connection refused or failed for : localhost/127.0.0.1:9000
[2015-02-01 14:37:23,570]  WARN - EndpointContext Endpoint : e2 will be marked SUSPENDED as it failed
[2015-02-01 14:37:23,571]  WARN - EndpointContext Suspending endpoint : e2 - current suspend duration is : 30000ms - Next retry after : Sun Feb 01 14:37:53 IST 2015
[2015-02-01 14:37:23,571]  WARN - LoadbalanceEndpoint AnonymousEndpoint Detect a Failure in a child endpoint : Endpoint [e2]
[2015-02-01 14:37:23,573]  WARN - ConnectCallback Connection refused or failed for : localhost/127.0.0.1:9003
[2015-02-01 14:37:23,573]  WARN - EndpointContext Endpoint : e3 will be marked SUSPENDED as it failed
[2015-02-01 14:37:23,574]  WARN - EndpointContext Suspending endpoint : e3 - current suspend duration is : 30000ms - Next retry after : Sun Feb 01 14:37:53 IST 2015
[2015-02-01 14:37:23,574]  WARN - LoadbalanceEndpoint AnonymousEndpoint Detect a Failure in a child endpoint : Endpoint [e3]
[2015-02-01 14:37:23,574]  WARN - LoadbalanceEndpoint Loadbalance endpoint : AnonymousEndpoint - no ready child endpoints
[2015-02-01 14:37:23,575]  INFO - LogMediator XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX = Log sequence hit
```